# Can't connect to redshift through a lambda procedure using specific cron schedule

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cron, psycopg2

I have a lambda function that connects to redshift using the python library psycopg2. If I use the following schedule expression through EventBridge, everiting runs ok:

```
cron(0/5 * * * ? *)
```

But, if I use a schedule expression like as follows, it raises an error:

```
cron(0 7 ? * MON-FRI *)
```

The error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<HOST>" (...) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
: OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/redshiftETL/lambda_function.py", line 29, in lambda_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/redshiftETL/lambda_function.py", line 22, in lambda_handler
    host=db_host)
  File "/var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "<HOST>" (...) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5439?
```

One important information is that redshift is configured to run 6am to 8pm, so the cron expression is within that period and the lambda function have the right connection to the VPC where the redshift cluster is alocated.

The following code is the snippet where I connect to the redshift. As you can see, nothing special:

```
# redshift connection
    db_database = '...'
    db_user = '...'
    db_password = '...'
    db_port = '...'
    db_host = '...'
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=db_database,
            user=db_user,
            password=db_password,
            port=db_port,
            host=db_host)
        conn.autocommit = True
        cur = conn.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
        <DO STUFF>
        raise e
```

I am going mad because I am not realizing what the cron expression have to do with the psycopg2 connection.

Any clue about what's going on?

Comment: Probably a Security Group issue. At the beginning of the script, try adding checking for Public and Private IPs.

Comment: The cron expressions in Lambda are in UTC timezone. Are you sure that matches the period that your Redshift cluster is active?

Comment: @MarkB, it could be, since I am running lambda in North Virginia (UTC -4) and I tried run it 7, 8 and 9 hours, but not 10:00, that matchs the 6am UTC - 4... I will try schedule to 10 and see what happends tomorrow... tnx.

Comment: Is it only failing some of the time, or every time? It might be trying to run at a time when Redshift is turned off.